Netcore API return 401 even when bearer token is included, after put [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = ...)] in my controllers
I want to make my API safe making that the User after registration, can get a token which can pass as a header in their request to get accest to the Api. Both funtionalities (registration and login) work properly. The problem comes when I put in my controller this :
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
after that, when i hadn't had issues making the login, now I cannot make any other registration or login cause I have this 401, even when the credentials are okay. (I fix this adding [AllowAnonymous] to the registration and login)
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 11 May 2024 17:42:33 GMT
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer



This are the main files I'm working in:
AuthenticationController.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GameStore.Api.Configurations;
using GameStore.Api.Dtos;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using RouteAttribute = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RouteAttribute;

namespace GameStore.Api.Controllers
{

    
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser>? _userManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AuthenticationController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        IConfiguration configuration
         )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _configuration = configuration;

        }

       
       
        //registration
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserRegistrationRequestDto requestDto)
        {
            //validate the incoming request
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //we need to check if the email already exist
                var user_exist = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(requestDto.Email);

                if (user_exist != null)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                    {
                        Result = false,
                        Errors = new List<string>()
                        {
                            "email already exist"

                        }

                    });
                }

                //create a user
                var new_user = new IdentityUser()
                {
                    //data which we receive from user
                    Email = requestDto.Email,
                    UserName = requestDto.Email
                };

                var is_created = await _userManager.CreateAsync(new_user, requestDto.Password);

                //check if it was created succesfully
                if (is_created.Succeeded)
                {
                    //generate the token
                    var token = GenerateJwtToken(new_user);

                    return Ok(new AuthResult()
                    {
                        Result = true,
                        Token = token
                    });
                }

                //if is_created is not succeded, we're gonna return an error
                return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                {
                    Errors = new List<string>(){
                        "Server error"
                    },
                    Result = false

                });
            }

            return BadRequest();

        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("login")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginRequestDto loginRequest)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //check if the user exists
                var existing_user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginRequest.Email);

                if (existing_user == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                    {
                        Errors = new List<string>()
                        {
                            "Invalid Payload"
                        },
                        Result = false
                    });
                }

                var isCorrect = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(existing_user, loginRequest.Password);

                if (!isCorrect)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                    {
                        Errors = new List<string>()
                        {
                            "Invalid Credentials"
                        },
                        Result = false
                    });
                }

                //in case is correct
                var jwtToken = GenerateJwtToken(existing_user);

                return Ok(new AuthResult()
                {
                    Token = jwtToken,
                    Result = true
                });
            }

            return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
            {
                Errors = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Invalid Payload"
                },
                Result = false
            });

        }

        //settings to generate the token
        private string GenerateJwtToken(IdentityUser user)
        {
            var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Secret").Value);


            var notBefore = DateTime.Now;

            
            var expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]{
                    new Claim("Id", user.Id),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
                }),

                Expires = expires,
                NotBefore = notBefore,
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            };

            var token = jwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var jwtToken = jwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return jwtToken;

        }

    }
}

Program.cs
using System.Text;
using GameStore.Api.Configurations;
using GameStore.Api.Data;
using GameStore.Api.Endpoints;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("GameStore");

builder.Services.AddSqlite<GameStoreContext>(connString);


builder.Services.Configure<JwtConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig"));


//it set the authentication mechanism; first the authentication, later authorization
//
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(configureOptions: options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;


})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false, //sometime in local machine can  generate an error cause we're ussing http rather than https, so it could generate an error; so we could put it in false to solve it
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtConfig:Secret"]!))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false).AddEntityFrameworkStores<GameStoreContext>();


builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

//this allow us to use the routes specified on our controllers
app.MapControllers();

app.MapGamesEndpoints();
app.MapGenresEndpoints();

await app.MigrateDbAsync();

app.Run();


and the file I'm using to make the requests
GET http://localhost:5068/games
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJJZCI6ImQ0ZDk4ZTQxLWIwYWQtNDRhYi04YzczLWRkYzg0MTZhOWE3MiIsInN1YiI6InBlZHJvQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoicGVkcm9AZ21haWwuY29tIiwianRpIjoiODUyZGYwYmQtMGQ5Yi00NTllLTk2MWMtZDRhYTU5ZGM3Y2E4IiwiaWF0IjoxNzE1MTEzNDg3LCJuYmYiOjE3MTUxMTM0ODcsImV4cCI6MTcxNTExNzA4N30.cJQvg-3xztxNo_rkUxRMSv2k5xhacyLlklTmZ9GsLLg

###
POST http://localhost:5068/api/Authentication/login
Content-Type:  application/json

{
    
    "Email":"pepepepa@gmail.com",
    "Password":"Pasword23777146_"
}

###
POST http://localhost:5068/api/Authentication/Register
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Name":"pepepepa",
    "Email":"pepepepa@gmail.com",
    "Password":"Pasword23777146_"
}



I tried changing some settings inside the method AddJwtBearer , inside Program.cs. Especifically I made ValidateIssuer = false. But still Not working.
builder.Services.Configure<JwtConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig"));


//it set the authentication mechanism; 
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(configureOptions: options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;


})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false, //sometime in local machine can  generate an error cause we're ussing http rather than https, so it could generate an error; so we could put it in false to solve it
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtConfig:Secret"]!))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false).AddEntityFrameworkStores<GameStoreContext>();

Adding [AllowAnonymous] to my Login and Registration I could get my tokens.
Now the problem  is that when I try to use that token that I got after my login in the header to try to get access to my Protected API, I have an
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token
I read an article about some problems that we can face when we work with JWT, and it was helpful. Debugging my code I found more information about the problem. Which I'm gonna check it out.
Here are some of the outputs I got debugging:
`Content root path: C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Documentos\programming\repos\My-projects\GameStore\GameStore.Api    
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[1]
      Failed to validate the token.
      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenMalformedException: IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).
The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.
       ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Byte[] Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Base64UrlEncoder.UnsafeDecode(System.ReadOnlyMemory`1<Char>)'.
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken.ReadToken(String encodedJson)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken..ctor(String jwtEncodedString)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.ReadToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[7]
      Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).
The token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware[0]
      Policy authentication schemes  did not succeed
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.` 


It's very strange that you want to keep the register also need authentication. This contains the logic issue, you must firstly login to get the token and then you could use that token to register user, but without registering the user how the user login in? The right action for this is not put the auth attribute for the controller just put it for the login method.

I fixed the main issue of be able to generate the token by just putting [AllowAnonymous] to get access to those routes.
Now the problem is use that token get access to my protected endpoint, which  shows me WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"  after sending the token in the header to get access to it. I think the main issue is in TokenValidationParameters but I'm still trying to fix it

Try setting the times using UTC. Depending on your timezone, this might mean your token is not yet valid
